# Extensions of LSTM for huge data

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, large-data, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Consider dealing with a huge high frequency financial data forecasting, RNN/LSTM is a popular way to solve the task. But the problem is that say you have 1 million data points and you want to predict the data for 10-period ahead, LSTM allows you to choose a look-back period so that it analyses more past information. But is there anyway to set up an "infinite" look-back memory LSTM, so that even you are dealing with the 20000th data point prediction, one of your cells can possess information from all the previous 19999 data point information?

Answer (score 3):

There's a very simple way to have "all previous time steps" available to the model: retain the memory state. At each time step, the memory is updated according to (1) the new time step; (2) the previous memory state and (3) the parameters (weights and biases) of the neural network. If you discard the memory state, then you're losing all of that accumulated information from the previous time-steps; but if you retain the memory state, then that information is available for making predictions in the future.